# Is Spring Data MongoDB MongoTransactionManager working with MongoClient

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using MongoTransactionManager base on official doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/reference/mongodb/client-session-transactions.html#mongo.transactions.reactive-tx-manager
One question, is this setup only supporting MongoTemplate running under transaction? The reason I am asking is that I tried to use MongoClient directly, but seems that won't work with transaction. As my understanding, MongoTemplate will bind to the current client session which is stored in  MongoTransactionManager, so by default MongoClient won't do that.
Also I failed to get client session from MongoTransactionManager or MongoTemplate. Was wondering if I can get that, then I can pass the clientSession to MongoClient methods like insertOne.... Is that also possible or I misunderstand something here.
Thank you!

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
@Autowired
private MongoClient mongoClient;
@Transactional
public void someMethod(){
  mongoClient.getDatabase("SomeDB").getCollection("SomeCol").updateOne... //won't work
  mongoTemplate.getCollection("SomeCol").updateOne... //works
  throw new RuntimeException();
}
```